# html 5 audio controls is not working in chrome and safari browser

Tags: html

i am used HTML 5 audio tag.Using that tag I have playing audio.This audio tag is working fine in Firefox and IE browser(including keyboard event).But it was not working in safari and chrome browser.
 using keyboard i not able to achieve play and pause the video in chrome and safari.

How to play audio using keyboard controls...

Please any one help to me.

Comment: It depends upon type of audio. Mp3 works fine in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used it working code on mozzila, chrome and opera

```
<audio controls="controls">
     <source src="{{r.prayerMedia}}" type="audio/mp3">
     Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific